# How to extract react js code from a website like google chrome dev tool does?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, extract

I would like to know how Google Chrome can display me the entire react source code of a frontend application when I visit a React website.

For example If I open a website I have this in the source tab of developer tools :

[image]

I would also like to know if there is a way to extract these react source ? Or if there is another tool to do that because reading the js file in the /js/ folder is way  harder.
Thank you

Comment: There's no magic API so devtools does this by analyzing the sourcemap comments in the scripts. You can inspect the source code of devtools to see how exactly it does this.

Comment: Thank you , do you know if there is a tool outside of google chrome that can do that ?